# I cannot get the integer value from unsafeMutablePointer<32> in swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode6, unsafe-pointers

I use swift and obj-c classes together in my project.

And I declare this in obj-c header file.

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *AppStoreId;
```

I want to use this obj-c code in my swift class:

```
NSDictionary *productParameters = @{ SKStoreProductParameterITunesItemIdentifier : [NSNumber numberWithInt:[appItem.AppStoreId intValue]]};
```

I convert it to swift like this:

```
var productParameters : NSDictionary = SKStoreProductParameterITunesItemIdentifier(NSNumber.numberWithInt(appItem.AppStoreId))
```

However, it gives me an error which says "UnsafeMutablePointer < Int32>" is not convertible to "Int32"

I also tried this:

```
var productParameters : NSDictionary = SKStoreProductParameterITunesItemIdentifier(NSNumber.numberWithInt(appItem.AppStoreId(IntegerType)).intValue)
```

But this time it gives me an error about using of IntegerType. 
I don't know what should I do. I am a beginner in swift and objective c. 
Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SKStoreProductParameterITunesItemIdentifier` is just a key for the dictionary, not a function to create one. You should use:

```
var productParameters : NSDictionary = NSDictionary(object: NSNumber.numberWithInt(appItem.AppStoreId.intValue), forKey: SKStoreProductParameterITunesItemIdentifier)
```

Comment: you are right, thank you! but how can I get intValue from appItem.AppStoreId?

Comment: I have written wrong code to get the `intValue`, sorry for that. Now the answer has been edited, all things seem right.

Comment: I cannot find an option like intValue, so I use toInt(). Thank you!